# RestEasy Async Controller Proper Usage

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, asynchronous, resteasy

I am trying to create a Async REST Service using RestEasy, but I can't find any documentation that shows a clean way of doing so. The only example I found is here:

https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/master/jaxrs/async-http-servlet-3.0/async-http-servlet-3.0-test/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/test/async/JaxrsResource.java

```
   @GET
   @Produces("text/plain")
   public void get(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response) throws Exception
   {
      response.setTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      Thread t = new Thread()
      {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
            try
            {
               System.out.println("STARTED!!!!");
               Thread.sleep(100);
               Response jaxrs = Response.ok("hello").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
               response.resume(jaxrs);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      };
      t.start();
   }
```

Creating a new thread in the method doesn't seem like the best way to do things in a production environment. I feel like I should be getting a thread from a thread pool or something.

Any suggestions or links to better examples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about using Thread pool. Let Spring take care of it for you.

Assuming you are using Spring as a choice for your application you could do something like.

You can define an Configuration class for Async Executors.

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Override
    @Singleton
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(env.getProperty("controller.threadPoolTaskExecutor.corePoolSize", Integer.class, 10));
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(env.getProperty("controller.threadPoolTaskExecutor.maxPoolSize", Integer.class, 100));
        taskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(env.getProperty("controller.threadPoolTaskExecutor.keepAliveSeconds", Integer.class, 60*5));
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(env.getProperty("controller.threadPoolTaskExecutor.queueCapacity", Integer.class, 10000));
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("controller-async-task-executor");
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new AsyncExceptionHandler();
    }

}
```

Here is how you can define the Exception Handler:

```
public class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AsyncExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
        logger.error("Error processing async request in method: " + method.getName(), ex);
    }   
}
```

Here is how your controller could look like:

```
@Inject
private AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor; 

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public void get(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response) throws Exception
{
    response.setTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    asyncTaskExecutor.submit(() -> {
        System.out.println("STARTED!!!!");
        Thread.sleep(100);
        Response jaxrs = Response.ok("hello").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
        response.resume(jaxrs);
    });
}
```